# does Google API KEY can be used only once or twice?

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I'm just develop Maps in my app's, and i'm curious why i just can used my API KEY only once or twice, and after that i need to open the console and simply `save` it to makes my API KEY works again,

**My question is:**

1. this is the behavior of API KEY itself or there's something wrong about my setup?
2. should i have two API KEY (one for IP Address and Android Apps for the 2nd)? even I'm accessing URL in my apps?

below is the success pic:
[image: Success]
and below is the failure with full message:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address <myIp>, with empty referer",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

[image: Failed]

EDITED:

I have add my restriction key on google console like this:
[image]

Comment: Off the top of my head, maybe you hit your daily usage quota.  If not, then maybe you aren't using the key you think you are.  Do you have a key `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` defined in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure, I've add `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` and `MyApiKey` in `meta-data` tag

Answer (score 4):

In cloud console you should set application restrictions for API key, you can choose one of this:

- None
- HTTP referrers (web sites)
- IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)
- Android apps
- iOS apps

Based on your error message i think you restricting based on IP address.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i think his IP changing every couple of days, and then he creating a new API key

Comment: Add that to your answer, then delete the comments :-)

Comment: @Alex I have add my restriction key so i can use the key for development purpose, but the problem still appear like my 1st question

Comment: @flix try to set the restriction to None, but better solution it is to use 'Android apps', this way you will restrict based on your package and SHA-1

Comment: @Alex so the next question is how to call the URL from my apps and used my `android apps key`? for now i just used default URL like browser do in my apps `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=LATLONG&destination=LATLONG&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=MyIpAddressKey` is there a better way?

Comment: @flix directions api is a web service, you should restrict it with IP:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46185362/1268507